# Socket.io emit event for only emitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, socket.io

i have image sending algorithm with socket.io and i decided to add "loading" message til image is loaded.

```
  $("#output").append(
        `<div id="loading-placeholder" style="opacity: 0"><div id="loading">${loadingSvg}</div></div>`
      );
```

and this div is removed when image is loadded

but problem is that i have image validation in server side

```
var ext = image.substring("data:image/".length, image.indexOf(";base64"));
console.log('extension ' + ext)
if(ext === 'jpeg' || ext === 'png' || ext === 'jpg'){
  chnm.in(socket.current_room).emit('img', {image: data.image, id: socket.id});
}
else{
  return false  
}
```

and it returns false if image extension is not jpeg || png || jpg, and in that case it returns false and image is never loaded so that loading svg stays forever. so if server side validation fails i want to return response to user that his image failed to send. how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using control message. Add `is_loaded` property.

```js
chnm.in(socket.current_room).emit('img', {
  image: data.image,
  id: socket.id,
  is_loaded: true
});
```

In case of faliure:

```js
chnm.in(socket.current_room).emit('img', {
  image: null,
  id: null,
  is_loaded: false
});
```

Another possible solutions:

- Simply check image for null.
- Add timeout on client side.

Comment: i have already made your both alternatives of your answer but problem is that your main answer will emit that event for both of users and i do not want it, if i used that kind of method i could just emit another event in else{} statement

Comment: you can emit it directly to single user using his ID. Their IDs are as well just rooms. Or just use `socket.emit(`.

Comment: so if i emit it to my socket id that's it?